# Algorithm to find the m smallest numbers in a list of n numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have to write an algorithm to find the "m smallest numbers in a list of n numbers". I don't understand what this line means. Do I have to find all the smallest numbers in a list and print them. For example if I have a list of say 4 elements [10, 20, 30, 40], do I have to print every number smaller than 40 one iteration at a time. Or is there some other meaning that's eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they're asking is this: given a list of n numbers, find the m smallest numbers. So if n = 10 and m = 5 and the list is this:

```
 Input: 1 4 2 6 3 6 2 4 6 1
Output: 1 1 2 2 3
```

A solution to this problem is to populate a max-heap with the first m numbers from the collection of n numbers. Then, go through the remaining n-m numbers in the list and compare to the max of the max-heap. If the number from the list is less than the max of the max list, remove the max from the max list and replace it with the current number from the list. Repeat until all numbers have been checked and then return the items in the m-heap.

The complexity of this is O(nlogm) since you do potentially one remove and one insert for each of the (n-m) elements in the list after taking the first m to prime the max heap.

Comment: Why not just quick select that is `O(n)`?

Comment: @Evg Quickselect is destructive to the original list. Unless you make a copy. Heap select is not. OP doesn't say whether he's allowed to modify the original list.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand, is that you have to write a function, that takes as parameter a number m, and return an array of number, which is of size m, and contains the m smallest numbers.
Taking your example, if we say that m is 2, we will return an array of 2 elements, containing the 2 smallest elements : `[10,20]`
If we set m to 3, the function would return `[10,20,30]`

Comment: So that's what the m means. I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. You can mark my answer as "Validated" by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in, if i helped ;)